# text keeps moving to the right when i change the footer width

Tags: html, css

I made this bread website and was on the footer. When changing the footer I found that the text keep moving to the right with the footer. How would I keep the text beside the images?

```css
footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <img src="https://onlycrumbsremain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/dinner-roll-9.jpg" alt="10 kinds of bread" width="400" height="300" align="left">

  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <img src="https://imgix.bustle.com/mic/kwojkqt6twmbxd7d525gm9bzrcfnccm940okdfbtbxc3c3lnchh2v6bh907bdigs.jpg?w=1200&h=630&fit=crop&crop=faces&fm=jpg" alt="10 kinds of bread" width="400" height="300" align="right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2021 Private Bread | The best online bread store!</p>
  </footer>
</main>
```

[image]

Comment: not reproduciable with the code provided. Add enough code to reproduce the issue. I assume it is caused becaus you style the website by using float instead of flexbox or css-grid. Also `<footer>` inside `<main>` is sementically a bad use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want your `<footer>` to be *outside* your `<main>`:

```css
footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <img src="https://onlycrumbsremain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/dinner-roll-9.jpg" alt="10 kinds of bread" width="400" height="300" align="left">

  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <img src="https://imgix.bustle.com/mic/kwojkqt6twmbxd7d525gm9bzrcfnccm940okdfbtbxc3c3lnchh2v6bh907bdigs.jpg?w=1200&h=630&fit=crop&crop=faces&fm=jpg" alt="10 kinds of bread" width="400" height="300" align="right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>&copy; 2021 Private Bread | The best online bread store!</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: down-voted for following reason: The answer is a vague "fix" to a very vague and unclear question. The problem mostlikely lies within the use of float. However with the code provided by the OP there is no way to know. As such a comment instead of an answer should have been given.

Comment: Oh okay. It worked! I'm new to HTML so I make some really obvious mistakes. Thanks!!

Comment: @tacoshy - that's fair; I made a few assumptions from a hunch before they had a proper [mcve].  In my defense, it _did_ solve their problem :)